# Route VPN traffic through socks proxy

Tags: vpn, android, route

There is no way to set proxy on an unrooted Android, but there is an option to connect to VPN.

In my network VPN connection is not allowed! so I am looking for a way to run a local VPN server on my computer and route it's traffic through a socks proxy (in a way that when I connect my android device to this VPN all my traffic routed through this socks proxy).

What's the options?

Comment: As I know [your freedom](http://www.your-freedom.net) do this with openvpn.

Comment: what routed through what?  http://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html#http

Answer (score -1):

so you set up your vpn server so that your android can talk to the local network through the vpn (exercise left to reader), now I am assuming that your vpn daemon does not have a socks configuration option which would make life much simpler, so you have to socksify your vpn server, which Either involves recompiling or preloading libsockswrap.so and configuring it so that it will not socksify local traffic. this is not a three banana job, this is hard work, plan to do this on a long weekend.

Comment: This answer is more appropriate as a comment instead. Please articulate your answer to make it more useful for the OP and other people as well.